# Mobile menu - CSS / DIV - Dim visible background around menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When my mobile menu opens, I would love the rest of the visible background (other than the menu itself) to 'dim.' (Both my pages and menu background are very white in general).

There is a plugin that offers this functionality but in trying to keep the website light, am trying to see if this is possible with just some lines of code?

Googling for quite a while came up with nothing other than the app which is a surprise... maybe I searched the wrong keywords?

Any ideas?

Here is my full code (not my original code, can link various parts to their respective Authors).

```
/*Change hamburger menu colour*/
span.mobile_menu_bar:before{
  color:#D7AF39;
}

/*Remove shading of top menu to match sub menu*/
.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children a {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

/** Divi Space slide in mobile edits**/

#mobile_menu { display: block !important; min-height: 100vh; top: 0; border-top: none; padding-top: 80px; z-index: 9998; }

.mobile_nav.closed #mobile_menu {
 transform: rotateY(90deg); -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
 transform-origin: right; -webkit-transform-origin: right;
 background: #fff; transition: .8s ease-in-out !important; }

.mobile_nav.opened #mobile_menu {
 transform: rotateY(0deg); -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
 transform-origin: right; -webkit-transform-origin: right;
 background: #fff; transition: .8s ease-in-out; }

.mobile_nav.opened .mobile_menu_bar:before {
 content: "\4d"; color: #D7AF39; }

.et_mobile_menu li a, .et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children>a {
    font-weight: 600;
        font-family: open sans;
        font-size: large;
}

@media(max-width: 980px) {

.et_header_style_split .mobile_menu_bar, .et_header_style_left .mobile_menu_bar { z-index: 9999; }

#main-header .container.clearfix.et_menu_container { width: 100%; }

.logo_container { padding-left: 30px; }

#et-top-navigation { padding-right: 30px; }

}

@media(min-width: 341px) {

#mobile_menu { width: 340px; margin-left: calc(100% - 340px); }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to help you if you provide some HTML.

Comment: I wouldn't know where to start.... I can switch the homepage into mobile and maybe pull up some code through Chrome if that helps? Is that what you mean?

Comment: What you can do is make a div and style it with a black background with less opacacity. When the user is in mobile responsive show the black background with dim opacity on the whole page and make the menu index greater then the div. You might need to add javascript

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to assert a blanket div over the entire page, beginning just below the menu bar, then setting that div's opacity to the desired level of dimming.

I have thrown together a very simple proof of concept.  Hover the dummy Menu button to observe the effect.  Take it onwards from there.

```css
body {
  --menu-height: 50px;
}

#page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#menu_bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: var( --menu-height);
  background-color: blue;
}

#menu_item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu_item:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: var( --menu-height);
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /* Ensure z-index is higher than page's content/data items */
  z-index: 2
}

#data {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="menu_bar">
    <div id="menu_item">Menu</div>
  </div>
  <div id="data">
    <span id="text">Hover the "Menu" button...</span><br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor etc
  </div>
</div>
```