# Reduce header size on mobile for WP/Divi

Tags: css, wordpress

Trying to reduce the header size for mobile users only my WP/Divi website. Already had a go at it for a few hours and am ready to leave it for another day.....

I tried the Divi walkthrough for this (https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/how-to-add-a-custom-fixed-header-for-mobile-using-divi) but I think the slide in menu has maybe overridden some code or something else is going on. With the Divi walkthrough I could get the hamburger menu icon to sit along the top edge and reduce the Logo to say 10px, but the logo would stay stuck in the middle and the header height would not change.

// I really need to set aside a few days to understanding all the WP code, commands and menus.

Anyway hope someone can point me in the right direction, I would be externally grateful!!

Here's all my extra CSS....

```
/*Make full header smoother to screen changes*/
@media (max-width: 1100px) 
{
    #top-menu li, #top-menu li a 
    {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    }
}


/* Remove bottom bar */
#footer-bottom
{
    display:none;
}


/*Centre footer menu*/
.bottom-nav 
{
    text-align: center;
}


/*Change hamburger menu colour*/
/*(https://www.twobluetoucans.co.uk/divi/styling-divi-mobile-menu/)
 */
span.mobile_menu_bar:before
{
  color:#1fd7e0;
}


/*Remove shading of top menu to match sub menu*/
.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children a 
{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}


/** Divi Space slide in mobile edits**/

/** (https://divi.space/divi-tutorials/css-only-slide-in-menus-for-divi/) **/

#mobile_menu { display: block !important; min-height: 100vh; top: 0; border-top: none; padding-top: 80px; z-index: 9998; }

.mobile_nav.closed #mobile_menu {
 transform: rotateY(90deg); -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
 transform-origin: right; -webkit-transform-origin: right;
 background: #fff; transition: .8s ease-in-out !important; }

.mobile_nav.opened #mobile_menu {
 transform: rotateY(0deg); -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
 transform-origin: right; -webkit-transform-origin: right;
 background: #fff; transition: .8s ease-in-out; }

.mobile_nav.opened .mobile_menu_bar:before 
{
    content: "\4d"; color: #1fd7e0;
}

.et_mobile_menu li a, .et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children>a 
{
  font-weight: 600;
    font-family: open sans;
    font-size: large;
}

@media(max-width: 980px) 
{
.et_header_style_split .mobile_menu_bar, .et_header_style_left .mobile_menu_bar 
    { 
    z-index: 9999;
    }

#main-header .container.clearfix.et_menu_container 
    {
    width: 100% 
    }

.logo_container 
    {
        padding-left: 30px;
    }

#et-top-navigation 
    {
        padding-right: 30px;
    }
}

@media(min-width: 341px) 
{
#mobile_menu 
    { 
    width: 340px; 
    margin-left: calc(100% - 340px);
    }   
}


/*Style the main header shadow border)*/
#main-header 
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(31, 215, 224,.3) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(31, 215, 224,.3) !important;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 
rgba(31, 215, 224,.3) !important;
}

#main-header.et-fixed-header 
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(31, 215, 224,.3) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(31, 215, 224,.3) !important;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 
rgba(31, 215, 224,.3) !important;
}


/*----------Header Menu and Sub Menu----------*/
#main-header .nav li ul
{
    border-top:1px solid 
rgba(31, 215, 224,.3);
}

#top-menu li li a:hover 
{
    color: #1fd7e0;
    background: white;
    opacity: 1!important;
}


/*Style main-footer top border*/
#main-footer
{
    border-top: solid 1px rgba(31, 215, 224,.3);
}
```

Please help if you can. Thank you =)

Comment: Could you add a link to a (development) version so we can have a look? Or add the HTML code? Without that code it is a bit difficult to determine the problem..

Comment: if this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60228488/mobile-menu-css-div-dim-visible-background-around-menu is still actual and if it's the same site, I can have a look into that as well.